# Wrong \rightmark in twocolumn mode

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, two-column, fancyhdr

I would like to use the "dictionary" style of page header, using `\rightmark--\leftmark` as suggested in [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package.

However, in `twocolumn` mode, `\rightmark` containts the *first* mark in the latter column, which is wrong: it should contain the *first* mark in the former column.

I know that using `multicol` package instead of `[twocolumn]` option or `\twocolumn` command would help, but I would like to avoid `multicol`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark{} -- \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\def\mysection#1{\section*{#1}\markboth{#1}{#1}}

% to provide dummy text and lots of sections
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{xs}
\def\xsect{%
  \stepcounter{xs}%
  \mysection{Section \Alph{xs}}
  \lipsum[\value{xs}]
}

\begin{document}

\xsect\xsect\xsect\xsect\xsect
\xsect\xsect\xsect\xsect\xsect

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

12345678